# How to call a stored procedure in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

A query for a stored procedure for multiple delete yield an error message shown way below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_dim_page(_page_id bigint)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $procedure$
    
begin
   delete from page_catalog where page_type_id = _page_id;
   delete from page_type where page_type_id = _page_id;
END;
$procedure$
;
```

**//entityclass**

```java
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "firstProcedure",
    procedureName = "delete_dim_page",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
            mode=ParameterMode.IN,
            name="_page_id",
            type = Long.class
        )
    }
)
```

**//service.java**

```java
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("firstProcedure");
    query.setParameter("_page_id", pageTypeId);
    query.execute();
```

yields

> ERROR: delete_dim_page1(bigint) is a procedure
> Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.

What is a recommendable way to call a stored procedure in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you are using spring data JPA.
You can just  create a JPA repository et call your procedure with a annotations like that :

```
public interface PageCatalogRepository extends JpaRepository<PageCatalogEntity , Void> {
    @Query(value = "CALL firstProcedure(:page_id);", nativeQuery = true)
    void deletePageCatalogById(@Param("page_id") Long page_id);
}
```

You can find other procedure calling methods here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures

Comment: use `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` annotation on top of `@Query` in order to make this work, i.e for stored procedures with no return.

Comment: what will be the @query for if I have "out" parameter also

Answer (score 1):

When using Spring Boot JPA, there are several ways to call stored procedures. A helpful set of annotations from Spring are available for working with stored procedures.

`@Procedure` annotation help to map the Stored Procedure defined in entity class.

When used the `@Procedure` annotation, got below exception `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.`

I referred to the [Spring Boot Stored Procedure Example](https://www.techgeeknext.com/storedproc) to resolve above exception and to understand how to use the alternative solution with `@Query` for stored procedure for select, update and delete with and without parameter.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "call get_employees")
    List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "call get_employee_id(:emp_id)")
    Employee getEmployeeById(@Param("emp_id") Long emp_id);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "call delete_emp_id(:emp_id)")
    void deleteEmployeeById(@Param("emp_id") Long emp_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, using transactional and modifying annotations, i was able to use a stored procedure which returns no output.

Comment: what will be the @query for if I have "out" parameter also

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using annotation @Procedure

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
...
public interface PageCatalogRepository extends JpaRepository<PageCatalogEntity , String> {
   @Procedure
   public String firstProcedure(Long page_id);
}
```